# Mesh loop analysis 2 loops, 2 voltage sources of different polarity

Tags: dc, kirchhoffs-laws, mesh-analysis

I'm having problems trying to work the following problem. The polarity is reversed on the right hand loop so I guess it becomes a -7v however does the current now go clockwise in loop one and anti in loop two?

[image]

So far I’ve got to:
Equation 1: \$-9I1+4I2=-28\$
Equation 2: I’m a little stuck on as the polarity is reversed. I’m thinking direction of current will be also, so would the equation be \$4I1-5I2=-7\$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I've identified two loops using two different colors and assuming both loops are clockwise. I've also identified a point where the loop equations start and end with an **x**:

[image]

The left (blue) loop equation is \$0\:\text{V}+28\:\text{V}-5\:\Omega\cdot I_1-4\:\Omega\cdot \left(I_1-I_2\right)=0\:\text{V}\$.

This certainly could be re-written as \$-9\:\Omega\cdot I_1+4\:\Omega\cdot I_2=-28\:\text{V}\$.

So I think you got a correct loop equation for the left loop and assuming both loops are going clockwise.

The right (red) loop equation is \$0\:\text{V}-4\:\Omega\cdot \left(I_2-I_1\right)-1\:\Omega\cdot I_2+5\:\text{V}=0\:\text{V}\$.

This could be re-written as \$4\:\Omega\cdot I_1-5\:\Omega\cdot I_2=-5\:\text{V}\$.

So perhaps you made a mistake in using 7 instead of 5? Was that a typo? Or, if not, what were you thinking there?

Comment: Yes definitely a typo should be -5 thank you so much for your help I appreciate it greatly

Comment: @Slayty No problem. :) I'm just glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you deal with mesh currents, you start with the assumption that all loops have current in the same direction. That is, all clockwise or all anticlockwise.

If, in the solution, a current is found to be negative, this simply means that in reality it's flowing the other way. You use the sign of the result to determine the actual direction. Remember that a negative current in one direction is the same as a positive current in the other direction.

If you've been consistent in your application of KVL, assigning correct signs to the potential differences as you travel around the loop, then the solution will be valid regardless of whether you "guessed" the current direction correctly or not.